# How to play a Voiceover notification when signal lost (i.e., no user interaction)?

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, voiceover

I've built a simple audio streaming app that looks like this:

[image]

When I lose the audio stream connection, my app overlays this screen on top of the UI:

[image]

I want to make the app accessible to folks who are blind or have low vision, so I want Voiceover to speak "Signal lost" and "Reconnecting" when the signal is lost and that overlay screen appears. This all happens WITHOUT ANY USER INTERACTION (akin to what happens when the screen times out, and VO says, 'screen dimmed'). It would be nice for VO to speak, "Signal regained" upon reconnection, too, but not absolutely necessary.

To make it even more tricky, when the 'signal lost' screen is up, the user should not be able to manipulate any of the other fields in the main UI below.

How do I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `UIAccessibilityPostNotification` to make an "announcement", which will cause it to read it out loud (only when VoiceOver is enabled):

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(
    UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification, 
    "Signal Lost" as NSString
)
```

The [documentation for `UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilityannouncementnotification?language=objc) explains the `NSString` argument and when it's suitable to use:

> This notification includes a parameter, which is an NSString object that contains the announcement. An assistive technology outputs the announcement string contained in the parameter.
>
> Use this notification to provide accessibility information about events that do not update the application user interface (UI), or that update the UI only briefly.

My recommendation would be to use announcements sparingly, but I'd say that events that happen without any user interaction is often — but not always — a good use of them.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could create an mp3 recording of the voice, then just us AVAudio to play it when the screen appears.

Answer (score 1):

If your'e set on playing Audio but don't have an MP3 you can use AVFoundation:

```
import AVFoundation
```

Create a function which synthesises a warning etc e.g.

```
/// Reads A Word Using Speech Syntheseis
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - word: String
func readWordAloud(_ word: String){

    //1. Create The Word To Be Read Aloud
    let wordReader = AVSpeechUtterance(string: word)
    wordReader.volume = 1

    //2. Pass It To The Speech Synthesizer
    let speechSynthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    speechSynthesizer.speak(wordReader)

}
```

Call the method like so:

```
readWordAloud("No Audio Available")
```

And to disable interaction with a `UIView` just use:

```
self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: Thank you! This will read the text all the time. I would like to have it so that the text would only be spoken when Voiceover is ON. Similar non-user-initiated events do occur, such as when the screen times out and VO speaks "screen dimmed." There must be some mechanism to do this.